# Simple processes in $L^2(dt \times \mathbb{P})$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Is there a nice form of  "simple processes"   i.e once we can approximate any adapted and $L^2(dt \times \mathbb{P})$ with. Or, if this is to general a nice class of simple procsses for a more restrictive class.

Comment: Really dont understand what you mean

Comment: Could you explain why you want to approximate simple processes? It's as if you want to approximate simple functions in Lebesgue theory, when they are in some sense the simplest function.